# How can i get attributes value in namednodemap

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get attributes value in namednodemap in the below code i want to get src attr

```
 $(resultdata).find("script[src]").prevObject.each((i,v)=>{
console.log($(v).get()[0].attributes);
.........code
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **this** out

```
 if(typeof $(v).attr('src') != "undefined"){ 
      console.log($(v).attr('src'));
  }
```